# Excel WEEKDAY starting from morninig not midnight

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm having trouble with excel function WEEKDAY. It returns weekday number, but always starting from 00:00 midnight, but in fact in the 3 shift company each working day finished at 6:00 morning the next day. For example guys work on Friday the whole night until Saturday 6:00 AM.
So ideally, the WEEKDAY should give me weekday counting from 6:00 and not from midnight. is this possible? thanks

Comment: Share your code please?.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 6 hours in the formula before you determine the weekday. If you want to compute the adjusted weekday of cell A1, just write

```
=WEEKDAY(A1-TIME(6,0,0),1)
```